# Android ViewAnimator and OutOfMemoryError

Tags: android, out-of-memory, viewanimator

this is the situation: I have a ViewAnimator with three different layouts. Each layout have a different backgroundimage. For xhdpi devices, the images are 1280x800 px large and have a size of ~150KB.
Now the problem: when I start the emulator with a size of 1280x800 and a density of 320dp, I always receive this exception:

```
09-02 08:22:46.408: D/dalvikvm(1291): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 428K, 51% free 2874K/5831K, external 18484K/20407K, paused 83ms
09-02 08:22:46.419: E/dalvikvm-heap(1291): 1366400-byte external allocation too large for this process.
09-02 08:22:46.498: I/dalvikvm-heap(1291): Clamp target GC heap from 25.089MB to 24.000MB
09-02 08:22:46.498: E/GraphicsJNI(1291): VM won't let us allocate 1366400 bytes
09-02 08:22:49.208: E/AndroidRuntime(1291): java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: bitmap size exceeds VM budget
```

Have anybody a solution or a workaround for my problem?
I read something about the BitmapFactory. Does it help? 
Best Regards!

**Edit:** Here is my code:
The layout file main_layout.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:gravity="center"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<ViewAnimator
    android:id="@+id/viewAnimator"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

   <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/LayoutMain"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:background="@drawable/background"
        ...some Buttons etc. ...
   </LinearLayout>

   <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/layoutGameMenu"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:background="@drawable/gameMenu"
        ...some Buttons etc. ...
   </LinearLayout>

   <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/layoutHighscores"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:background="@drawable/highscores"
        ...some ListViews etc. ...
   </LinearLayout>

</ViewAnimator>
</LinearLayout>
```

And the MainActivity:

```
private ViewAnimator va;   

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
     setContentView(R.layout.main_layout);
     va = (ViewAnimator) findViewById(R.id.viewAnimator);
     ....
}

....
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if(event.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
        if (va.getCurrentView() == findViewById(R.id.layoutHighscores)) {
            va.setInAnimation(inFromRight);
            va.setOutAnimation(outToLeft);
            va.setDisplayedChild(0);
            return true;
        }
        if (va.getCurrentView() == findViewById(R.id.layoutGameMenu)) {
            va.setInAnimation(inFromLeft);
            va.setOutAnimation(outToRight);
            va.setDisplayedChild(0);
            return true;
        }
    } 
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```

With this, I can switch between the mainmenu, the highscores and the gamemenu with buttons to start a gamemode. I choose this because I want the "cool" view animations.

I have tried to solve it with the BitmapFactory methods, but there are no changes.

```
public static Bitmap decodeSampledBitmapFromResource(Resources res, int resId, int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {

    // First decode with inJustDecodeBounds=true to check dimensions
    final BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
    BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, resId, options);

    // Calculate inSampleSize
    options.inSampleSize = calculateInSampleSize(options, reqWidth, reqHeight);

    // Decode bitmap with inSampleSize set
    options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
    return BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, resId, options);
}

public static int calculateInSampleSize(BitmapFactory.Options options, int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {
// Raw height and width of image
final int height = options.outHeight;
final int width = options.outWidth;
int inSampleSize = 1;

if (height > reqHeight || width > reqWidth) {
    if (width > height) {
        inSampleSize = Math.round((float)height / (float)reqHeight);
    } else {
        inSampleSize = Math.round((float)width / (float)reqWidth);
    }
}
return inSampleSize;
}
```

Comment: have you tried on real device?

Comment: No, I don't have a device in this size. That's why I need to try it on a emulator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a lesson that covers this situation in the *Android Training* section of the main Android site.  The lesson, [Displaying Bitmaps Efficiently](http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/index.html), is split into four sections, includes working examples, and supports API level 7 and up (I assume this isn't a problem.)

If that doesn't help I'd suggest posting some code so more specific help can be given. ;-)

Comment: Hello, I have tried it with the BitmapFactory.decode* methods as shown on [this link](http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html) but there is no effect. I still receive the exception. If you wish I can post some code, but I don't believe it would help because I only set the backgroundimages in the layout with: android:background="@drawable/background". Best Regrads.

Comment: @Namenlos, it is _always_ worth adding code IMHO.  If nothing else it gets more eyes on it.  If by any chance you are worried about showing too much of your code (seems a common problem) then I suggest mocking up an example.  Just test it to ensure it gives the same error ;-)

Comment: you are right. I added some code. As you can see, I have tried it with the BitmapFactory. But there was no effect.
But there must be a possibility to load more than one picture. That's crazy >.<